# How do I attach a php file to an arbitrary slug and still have access to the wp-core functions?

Tags: php, slug

Based on an example found [here](http://www.mihaivalentin.com/wordpress-tutorial-load-the-template-you-want-with-template_redirect/) and several others, I am trying to load a non wordpress page from a specific URL while having access to the wordpress core.

I have the following code (which seems to work as expected) to hook into the `template_redirect` action:

```
function templateRedirect() {
    global $wp;
    if ( $wp->query_vars['pagename'] == 'nlm-admin-thumbnail' ) {
        global $wp_query;
        // if we have a 404 status
        if ($wp_query->is_404) {
            // set status of 404 to false
            $wp_query->is_404 = false;
            $wp_query->is_archive = true;
        }
        // change the header to 200 OK

        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        //load our template
        include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/thumbnail.php' );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'templateRedirect');
```

My problem comes when executing the code in `thumbnail.php`.  This file is supposed to download a thumbnail of a webpage and output the raw image.  The nlm-admin-thumbnail slug is used as the src for an image tag.

When I execute the thumbnail.php I keep getting `undefined function some_wp_function()`.  I have included http.php and class-http.php from the wp-includes folder.  Now that I have included those, the next error is `undefined function apply_filters()`.

Does loading a php file in this way not give me access to the wp core, and should apply_filers() not accessable?

Comment: Try loading wp-load.php

Comment: I thought by hooking into template redirect I would avoid that and all the problems that go with it.

Comment: Calling add_action() justs adds some objects? to some array? it doesn't actually load any PHP files that I am aware of.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are trying to to but BackPress which is just the WordPress core available as a free download may be something toconsider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this pretty regularly and have no issue with using functions in WordPress core. You can hook a bit earlier though and skip the 404 and header bits. In `functions.php`:

```
function wpa88013_parse_query( $wp ){
    if ( 'nlm-admin-thumbnail' == $wp->query_vars['pagename'] ) {
        include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/thumbnail.php' );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpa88013_parse_query' );
```

And some example code in `thumbnail.php`:

```
<?php
$content = "foo\n\nbar";
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );

$post_id = 1;
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id );
```

I've just tested this in the twentytwelve theme and it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Milo.  Will hooking in here let me set my own headers?  My script returns an image built in memory (the actual image, not a url to a file).

Comment: hook the `parse_request` action instead, this happens before WordPress sends any headers. see the [action reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) for the order of actions.